# Why my social media panel glitch when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a social media panel, I want it when the scroll down panel disappears and the x icon changes to a share icon.

the code that I made when I clicked the x panel disappeared was working properly.

but when I want to make a function (below) when the scroll down panel disappears, what happens is my panel has a glitch.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      toggleMenu();
    }
});
```

does anyone know where the problem is?

This is my [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/fikryrmdhna/pen/xxVLzaR)

**HTML**

```
<div id="floatingPanel">
   <div class="panel-socmed open">
      <a href="#" class="instagram">
         <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="facebook">
         <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="twitter">
         <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="youtube">
         <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="linkedin">
         <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div id="closeShare">
       <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Full JS**

```
function toggleMenu() {
   if ($(".panel-socmed").hasClass("open")) {
       $(".panel-socmed").removeClass("open");
       $("#closeShare").find(".fa-times").hide();
       $("#closeShare").find(".fa-share-alt").show();
   } else {
       $(".panel-socmed").addClass("open");
       $("#closeShare").find(".fa-times").show();
       $("#closeShare").find(".fa-share-alt").hide();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#closeShare').click(function() {
      toggleMenu();
    });
  
  //The problem is in code below
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
          toggleMenu();
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) fires at a high rate (every few pixels you scroll). Meaning the menu will keep opening and closing. Try to seperate the open en closing into their own functions and call them separately based on some conditions.

```
function toggleMenu() {
   if ($(".panel-socmed").hasClass("open")) {
       openMenu();
   } else {
       closeMenu();
  }
}

function openMenu() {
  $(".panel-socmed").removeClass("open");
  $("#closeShare").find(".fa-times").hide();
  $("#closeShare").find(".fa-share-alt").show();
}

function closeMenu() {
  $(".panel-socmed").addClass("open");
  $("#closeShare").find(".fa-times").show();
  $("#closeShare").find(".fa-share-alt").hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#closeShare').click(function() {
      toggleMenu();
    });
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
          openMenu();
       }else{
          closeMenu();
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: oh i dont know about the scroll event issue. But thank you so much for your solution, it works for me! @Reyno